# Problem with locale and language, I Type using Persian layout, but the (system) inserts English characters!

Tags: gnome, keyboard, xorg, keyboard-layout, wayland

As I explained in the title;

I just installed Ubuntu 18.10 like how I always install last versions,
And now there are some problems:

1. The default locale for Iranians is `fa_IR`, but the installer setups Ubuntu by using `az_IR` as default locale. I know how can I generate and set fa_IR locale. But I want to know where can I patch a fix for this? Where should I start? (This problem started from 17.04 version)
2. Now in 18.10, I can't even type in Persian! I switch to Persian, Type, But System inserts English Chars. Not sure but I think it's a problem with Gnome 3.30, cause I have this issue in new Gnome on Arch setup too.

Is there any fix?
Or do I need to downgrade?

Comment: Tested, There is no issue in Wayland session! So It's an issue by X.

Comment: Are you talking about the online screen keyboard?

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I'm talking about the whole system keyboard, Including my laptop keyboard, and the Gnome on-screen keyboard! There is no Persian/Arabic characters in Gnome X session.
You can easily reproduce the issue, Just: 1. Login to Gnome Xorg. 2. Add Persian layout to your gnome keyboard layouts, Switch to it. 3. Try to type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm.. Yes I could reproduce it.

Then I downgraded these packages to the bionic versions:

```
xserver-common
xserver-xephyr
xserver-xorg-core
xserver-xorg-legacy
xwayland
```

When doing so, a few packages were removed. I don't remember which ones exactly, but I think it was some `xserver-xorg-video-*` packages.

Anyway, after that (and rebooting) it started to work.

Then I have upgraded to the cosmic versions again, and installed the `xserver-xorg-video-all` package, and it's still working.

So this seems to be some kind of subtle bug.

Comment: Thanks for your time. So it's a bug with X?!! not a missing package or configuration?
What about my first question? where should I patch a fix to correct default locale?

Comment: @MerajSahebdar: Can't really tell the nature of the bug. My observation indicates that some installed package messes it up. It would be great if you could file a bug, probably against the `xorg-server` source package. As regards the locale, it reminds me of [bug #1763025](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1763025). I suppose you get the desired locale if you pick the Persian language in the installer. Otherwise the installer 'guesses'. Why do you want to patch it? Are you setting up multiple machines or something?

Comment: Just because I want my lovely OS does everything correctly! Even I select `English` installer will setup `az_IR` for me :| and it's far away from English and Persian. Before 17.04 or maybe 16.10 the installer always detected the local truly! I don't know whether it's a bug by detector, or someone changed it! I'm sure Iranians speak in Persian not Azerbaijani.

Comment: @MerajSahebdar: `az_IR` is new, and the installer 'guesses' in such a case, i.e. it picks the first `_IR` locale in alphabetical order. Yes, it's kind of a bug; I mentioned an applicable bug number.